# CSRF protection when not using forms to submit data

Tags: django, csrf

I have a list (that is forms in a formset) of files and for each item I have a button that can delete these files and their corresponding database records. Currently I am using an AJAX/JQUery call to achieve this.

The button does not submit some kind of form but rather makes a POST request via AJAX ' directly' and I am wondering whether or not this is a safe way to do this w.r.t. CSRF? I have tried a number of things like adding the CSRF token to the header as per the documentation and using the @csrf_protect decorator. The function works and doesn't throw any errors but I'm not sure whether this is because the CSRF check are comming through or whether they simply never take place. When I look at my request.POST the CSRF-token is not listed, which is the case when I use a standard form approach.

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
def delete_file(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        file_id = request.POST.get('file_id')
        try:
            SFile.objects.get(FILE_ID=file_id).delete()
        except:
            file_id = 0

            return JsonResponse({'file_id':file_id})

    raise Http404
```

AJAX/JQuery

```
$('#file-list').on('click','.delete-file-button', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var file_id2 = $(this).attr('id')
    var post_url = $(this).attr('data-url');
    form_data = {file_id: file_id2}

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        data : form_data,
        type : "POST",
        success : function(data) {
            $(file_item).remove();
            var filecount = $('.file-item').length-1;
            $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(filecount);
            $('#id_form-INITIAL_FORMS').val(filecount);
        }
    });
});
```

template

```
<div class="item_list" id="file-list">
    {% for file_form in file_formset %}
        <div class="item file-item">
            ...
            <button class="delete-file-button" id="{{ file_form.instance.FILE_ID }}" data-url="{% url 'delete_file' %}">
                <span class="icon-delete-0001"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Simple way to check if that works: remove header (and just header) from your ajax request and leave `@csrf_protect` in place. If csrf is working, that should throw an error. If it does not, check your middlewares, because that's where CSRF check is happenning.

Comment: Note that a valid requests needs the cookie, and either the header or a POST field. Since your requests has the appropriate header, it doesn't need the POST field.